# Is there a way to create a c++ gui game without win32 api, openGL, direct X and stuff?

Tags: c++, api

If not, what are the closest pl and c++ api to c++ syntax that can make gui games?

Comment: You could write your own OS and memory map the framebuffer and write directly to it. This question is kind of vague as to what exactly you want as most GUI's require a library because drawing to the screen is not easy.

Comment: Wait, why are posing such a requirement in the first place? Are they too hard to learn or something?

Comment: @chris: If he thinks they're too hard to learn, wait til he has to push his own pixels.  I almost wanna be there for that.  :)

Comment: Just a thought. The alternatives of making an OS are much worse though lol

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can always write your own operating system and device drivers for the bare metal. Then build your game on top of that. If you don't want to write a full blown OS, you can still do the device drivers yourself. If you don't want to implement the device drivers, then you can do all the content generation without aid of any special purpose hardware and let to the CPU all the heavy lifting by writing a software rasterizer. But you'll still need APIs provided by the OS to output the content. Those APIs would be DirectX and Win32 API (on Windows).

Comment: And if I use java, could it be possible to make a gui game?

Comment: @NunoValBento: Yes, but you'd have a hard time making C++ code out of it (referring to the question's tags).  And it wouldn't be anywhere near as close to the hardware as you seem to want to be.  It'd use DirectX or OpenGL behind the scenes.  And still, you'd have an API you have to learn in order to do anything useful.  There's no way around that last part -- even video cards themselves have interfaces you'll have to learn, if you found a way to talk directly to them.

Comment: Java adds just another layer on top of all those API and the CPU architecture. But I think I know understand the nature of your question: You want to be plattform independent. Well, there are game development frameworks like Irrlicht Engine, Ogre, Crystal Space or the commercial engines like Source, Unreal, CryEngine or similar, which abstract all the OS dependent stuff away.

Answer (score 3):

Wait...so you want to write a Windows GUI game without using any of the APIs that give you access to the screen in the first place?

No.  Not possible.  Windows makes a point of preventing you from having unfettered access to the hardware.  (One could say its *whole point* is to manage the hardware for you, and keep programs from trampling all over each other when they want to do something.  It couldn't do that if it let you do whatever you please with the video card.)  The closest you'll get to it would be DirectX.  Possibly SDL, but it seems even that uses DirectX behind the scenes on Windows.

If you want to write your own OS or something, or use a crappy barebones OS as a base, it'd be doable.  But then it wouldn't be a Windows game.  You could conceivably also write a service that hands you a frame buffer or something...but then, you'd be writing a half-assed version of DirectX.  And making all of your users' machines unstable, which would eventually lead to you not having any users.  (And to top it all off, *you'd have to use the Win32 API to run as a service*.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retain any sanity, then no .  The alternative to OS API's is... there isn't any.

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah if you're intending on writing a game that'll generate nothing more than ascii art in a command console. How are you going to handle video cards, sound cards, input devices, network interfaces, GPU acceleration, shaders, frame rates etc.. without Win32 api, OpenGL, DirectX?

Answer (score 0):

Write your game for a platform where you can access hardware directly, e.g. x86 PC + DOS and run it there or in a VM like DosBox.

Comment: Never worked worth a damn for me.  (The VM route, that is.)  Text always worked fine, but graphics always seemed to be broken.

Comment: @cHao: Either you didn't do it right or you hit some VM bugs.